# Average calculation of various columns of stored procedure in java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2012, average

I have a stored procedure in which avg_pressure column is empty.I have to create a method to calculate the average of various columns in a row and put that calculated average values in respective row and column.My average calculated method is:-

```js
public int  arrayAverage() throws NumberFormatException, SQLException {
       int sum = 0;
       int count = 0; 
      getConnection();
    String A= rs.getString("st1_vs1_bag1_rb");
    String B= rs.getString("st1_vs1_bag2_rb");
    String C= rs.getString("st1_vs1_bag4_rb");
       for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
           {
              
            sum +=Integer.parseInt(A+B+C);
         
               count++;
                    }
```

My table data is retrieved from following method:-

```js
public String[][] getDbTable()
  {
 
 
   int i = 0;
   String [][]a = new String[3600][16];
   System.out.println("datetime is" +d);
   System.out.println("datetime is" +currentDate);
   try
   {
              con = getConnection();
          
        
              String sql = "exec vcs_gauge @gauge_name=?,@first_rec_time=?,@last_rec_time=?";
             DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
              System.out.println("date is "+df.format(currentDate));
              clstmt = con.prepareCall(sql); 
              clstmt.setString(1,"vs1_bag");
            
     clstmt.setString(2, "2014-09-01 10:00:00");
     clstmt.setString(3, "2014-09-01 11:00:00");
    
               clstmt.execute();
               rs = clstmt.getResultSet();
            
    
    while (rs.next())
    {
     for(int j=0; j<16; j++)
     {
       a[i][j] = rs.getString(j+1);
     }
    
     i++;
    }
   
   }
 
   catch( Exception e )
   {
    System.out.println("\nException in Display Bean in getDbTable(String code):"+e);
   }
   finally
   {
    
    closeConnection();
   }
   return a; 
  }
```

But when i run arrayAverage() method through jsp then following exception is thrown.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set is closed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depends of the type of pooling you are using, when you close the Connection, the objects Statement and ResultSet are going to be closed too.

Try to retrieve the data you want before colsing the Connection.